# Handling Simultaneous HTTP calls to Spring Rest Controller

Tags: spring, multithreading, rest, http, simultaneous

I am trying to receive simultaneous calls to this controller from the client. Client is trying to send the chunks of a single file and server is trying to first collect all those chunks in a MultipartFile array then reassembling when all chunks are received. However, I don't know if this code is thread safe, since I have shared resource like file array. I create that when first chunk is received. I am confused because this code functions in an interesting way. For example it enters to (file == null) statement 4-5 times. I would appreciate if someone can help to make this code stateless or thread safe!

```
@PostMapping("/mtupload/chunk")
public ResponseEntity<String> getMultithreadedUpload(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
                                             @RequestParam("fileSize") String fileSize,
                                             @RequestParam("chunkSize") String chunkSize,
                                             @RequestParam("numberOfChunks") String numberOfChunks,
                                             @RequestParam("chunk") MultipartFile chunk,
                                             @RequestParam("chunkId") String chunkId,
                                             @RequestParam("fileId") String fileID) throws IOException {

    int chunkkSize = Integer.parseInt(chunkSize);
    int fileeSize = Integer.parseInt(fileSize);
    int chunkkId = Integer.parseInt(chunkId);
    int numberOfChunkss = Integer.parseInt(numberOfChunks);
    int fileIdd = Integer.parseInt(fileID);

    if(file == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Server created array of length " + numberOfChunkss + " Inside chunk " + chunkId);
        
        //static MultipartFile[] file is defined as global variable
        file = new MultipartFile[numberOfChunkss];
    }
    if(chunk.getSize() == 0)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(" Server failed to get chunk "+ chunkId + " !", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    System.out.println("Server got chunk " + chunkId );

    file[chunkkId] = chunk;
    System.out.println("Chunk size in File " + chunkId  + " : " + file[chunkkId].getSize());

    // call to store the file when all chunks are received.
    //        storageService.storeChunks(file, fileName, numberOfChunkss, chunkkSize);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(" Server got chunk "+ chunkId + " !", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not thread-safe. It is like that more than one thread will create a new `file`. You can declare file volatile and add synchronization to the null check block:

```
if(file==null) {
  synchronized(this) {
    if(file==null) {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming chunkids are unique, the resulting code would be thread-safe.

Comment: could you elaborate more on why you check if file is null or not twice?

Comment: It is a very common pattern. Google for "double if synchronization in Java" and you should find a lot of articles. The first check avoids the unnecessary synchronization overhead after the file is initialized. The second check is necessary to make sure file is still not initialized after the first `if` and before the `synchronized` block. `file` must be volatile to make sure once it is initialized, it is visible to all other threads.